# Is it possible to use Webpack import inside script tag of Laravel blade file

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel mix(v4-beta) which is a layer on top of Webpack. I want to use Webpack imports like following inside `<script>` tag of blade file:

```
import $ from "jquery"
```

Is it possible or I have extract the code to a separate .js file?

Comment: Yes. Did you actually try it before asking your question?

Comment: @MartinBean I don't think it's possible to get Mix to process `<script>` tags in Blade files. Can you link to docs on doing this?

Comment: Import is not webpack specific. It's [JavaScript syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the reason we use webpack is to convert it to something that works on older browsers, and yes for that you need JS files to work with

Comment: @MartinBean Yes, I have searched the docs both on laravel.com and laravel-mix.com.

Comment: The problem I am facing is that if I use `import $ from "jquery"` in some scripts then $ under `window` is getting undefined. So I am trying to use import inside `<script>` tags.

Comment: @im_tsm If you look at a brand-new Laravel install's `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file, you'll find `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');` used to make jQuery available globally. (You should take a look at the overall fresh-start Laravel install and how it handles JS, incidentally.)

Answer (score 0):

1/a. Add jquery dependency with Webpack (jquery is a separate js lib/file)

( 1/b. Or, if you want to use a CDN ("external") you can https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/ )

then:

2. You can insert page-specific javascript files into your tempaltes if you control the output (files) with webpack. See: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/

And check the "code spitting" documentation too: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/